# Проблема с кодировкой во время получения JSON данных

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Формирую массив для отправки в файл ajax.php

```
    var cod     = $("table tr:not(:first)").find("td:first"),
        arrCod  = [],
        arrLink = [];
```

Убираю лишние пробелы

```
            $.each(cod, function(i,e){
                if( $(e).text().trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ') != "Код" ) {
                    arrCod.push(encodeURIComponent($(e).text()));    
                }

            })

            var data = "cod="+JSON.stringify(arrCod);   
            $.ajax  ({
                url:"ajax.php",
                type:"POST",
            //    dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

В php файле получаю данные

```
    $data = stripslashes(strip_tags($_REQUEST["cod"]));
    $data = json_decode($data);

    print_r($data);
```

На выходе получаются данные такого типа

```
    [27] => Р“8416
    [28] => Р“8417
    [29] => Р“8418
    [30] => Р“5988
    [31] => 64814
    [32] => 64804
    [33] => РљРѕРґ
    [34] => 85166
```

Подскажите, как исправить, чтобы данные были в нормальном виде, а не "битые"

Comment: Зачем вы все енкодите а затем еще и в джсон строку кладете? Браузеры давно научились правильно передавать джс-объекты

Comment: напишите как правильно будет выглядеть код, пожалста

Comment: оставьте `arrCod.push($(e).text())` и `data = {cod: arrCod}` и все.на стороне сервера в `$_POST['data']`  получите  массив того что отправляли.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем что то декодить на стороне сервера посмотрите что он возвращает (print_r($_POST)).

И нет необходимости в данных преобразованиях,

> $data = stripslashes(strip_tags($_REQUEST["cod"]));

по факту они вам и возвращают результат в том виде который вы получаете

Answer (score 1):

В начале php скрипта пропишите

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```